# googleway package produces blank plot

Tags: r, geospatial, googleway

I'm unable to generate any map using the googleway package.  I have installed it both from github and cran and have a google maps javascript API key.  I have tried some very basic code:

```
google_map(key=gkey)
```

Am using RStudio - the output window just shows blank white... same when trying within a shiny app.

Any thoughts on what's causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a little more background, please? What is "gkey" for example? What data have you loaded into your workspace?

Comment: gkey holds the value of my google api key.  i'm not using any data here, just testing whether it will plot any map at all...

Comment: The problem is hard to reproduce...

Comment: what version of `RStudio`, and have you tried opening the map in a browser?

Comment: And have you tested your key is activated? see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/44881447/5977215

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I have tested the key and it is valid.  I used the code at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map and was able to produce a map and view it in the browser.  How do i export a googleway map to html for opening in a browser?  I am using Rstuio 1.1.383.

Comment: @dataNbeer In the 'Viewer' pane there is a button called 'show in new window' when you hover over it. This should open it in a browser.